# PHP Interactive - Load File From Command Line

Tags: php, bash, shell

Is there a way, from a bash script and/or a terminal, to run php interactively and load in a predefined file at the same time?

Essentially, I want to do the following two steps in a single step:

```
shell# php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > require_once('ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_FILE');
```

I tried using `php -a --file='ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_FILE'` but the functions I want to load do not become available in interactive mode.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have a `test.php` file with this contents

```
<?php
function asd() {
    echo "Hi!";
}
?>
```

You must use:

```
php -a -d auto_prepend_file=test.php
```